# Hiding tooltip for a asp.net checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, tooltip

Is there a way of hiding a tooltip for a asp.net checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `title` attribute from the checkbox.

Comment: will i still be able to get to the tooltip value at serverside code

Comment: No, you'll have to store it server-side.